# Can a wizard's Patronus change over time?

Tags: harry-potter

> *"After all this time, Severus?"*
>
> *"Always..."*

I can't find the quote at the moment, but Albus and Severus's conversation seems to imply that a wizard's Patronus could change over time. Is this possible?

> If Snape had ever properly grieved and freed himself from his love of Lily, could his Patronus have changed from a doe into something else?

Comment: **dlanod**'s answer is spot on. Regarding whether Snape's Patronus could have changed if he had properly processed his love for and loss of Lily, I *think* so. It's not my story, but I always found a doe to be quite feminine for Snape (who is not an effeminate character) I always pictured Snape's Patronus as being, oh, a flock of bats or something like that. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess - It seems that the answer is [no](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/601377849744990208), not unless he somehow found another eternal love...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes.  Nymphadora's Patronus changes to a werewolf after meeting and falling in love with Remus.

According [to Rowling](http://web.archive.org/web/20100116151032/http://www.mugglenet.com/app/news/full_story/1156), this is a fairly common occurrence:

> J.K. Rowling: No, the Patronus often mutates to take the image of the
>   love of one's life (because they so often become the 'happy thought'
>   that generates a Patronus).

Answer (score 5):

Since your question is in two parts, the answers are yes and no (in that order)

- It's clear that a patronus can indeed change, as evidenced by Nymphadora's Patronus changing to a wolf after she falls in love with Remus.
- JK Rowling has confirmed in a recent tweet that that change will only occur under the influence of '**eternal**' love. The clear implication is that if your **love is sufficiently weak that you could "*get over it*", then it won't change your patronus form in the first place**

---

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## A JKR Pottermore writing says yes, it can.

In a writing on Pottermore, JKR says that someone’s Patronus can change form due to at least three different reasons: if they suffer a loss, fall in love, or their personality changes a lot.

> The form of a Patronus may change during the course of a witch or wizard’s life. Instances have been known of the form of the Patronus transforming due to bereavement, falling in love or profound shifts in a person’s character. Thus Nymphadora Tonks’s Patronus changes from a jack rabbit to a wolf (not a werewolf) when she falls in love with Remus Lupin. Some witches and wizards may be unable to produce a Patronus at all until they have undergone some kind of psychic shock. 
> <sub><sup>*[Patronus Charm (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/patronus-charm)*</sup></sub>

According to this, then, it wouldn’t necessarily require external circumstances for someone’s Patronus to change - a significant change in personality can be enough. So yes - a Patronus can change over time.

*Valorum’s answer already covers whether Snape’s Patronus would change, specifically.*