# Is it necessary for the Patronus and Animagus forms to be the same?

Tags: harry-potter, patronus-charm

Minerva McGonagall's Animagus form is a cat. Her Patronus is also a cat. We know that James Potter was a stag Animagus, and his Patronus was a stag as well. I'm not sure if Sirius Black's Patronus ever appeared in the books, but I am pretty much sure it would have been a dog.

Is the form of an Animagus directly related to the form of a Patronus?

Just to clarify, in an instance that the Patronus changes (as it is [established by canon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/15292/20774)), does this mean that the Animagus form also changes? 
Or is it impossible for both to change for an Animagus?

Comment: Three people does not a good statistic make.

Comment: To correct you, I only gave two. But you see, I did not claim that there IS a direct relation, I am asking IF there is one given the observation.

Comment: @Richard it does nothing of the sort. It merely indicates that a patronus _can_ change, based on what happy memory it's tied to. But that doesn't mean that it changes for animagi; perhaps for them it's tied to the same part of their personality their animal form comes from.

Comment: Thanks @SQB, I have actually edited the question to clarify what exactly I meant and what happens to the animagus form considering the changes of the Patronus.

Comment: Hi @Kevin, Richard, SQB and I were discussing a while ago regarding the duplicity of my question. If you would check the last paragraph of my question, edited for clarification, I am asking about the existence of the connection between the Animagus and Patronus form.

Comment: @gelolopez the last paragraph makes it even more clear this is a duplicate. Compare the questions, "in an instance that the Patronus changes (as it is established by canon), does this mean that the Animagus form also changes?" and "If Tonks (or any other wizard who had their Patronus change) had been an animagus, would her animagus have changed as well?".  Both are clearly asking, if a patronus changes does the animagus form change.

Comment: But you see, I am actually asking if it is necessary for the Patronus and Animagus forms to be the same.

Comment: I would think so, based on those two examples. In fact, if we only had one, it would already be a strong lead. I suppose it could be that the patronus and animagus shapes just kind of happen to be the same for that person, but there are millions of animal species on earth - what are the chances? And we don't just have one. We have two, and no counterexamples. I'd say, even without a clear in-universe explanation, that the answer to your question is almost certainly yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is currently unknown.**

The number of people who can cast a corporeal Patronus is vanishingly small. The number of Animagi (registered or otherwise) is even smaller.

James and McGonagall are the only two characters in canon who are in both groups. It could be a coincidence that their Animagus forms and Patronuses happen to be the same; we just don’t have enough  information to tell.

The canon has scant information about Animagi who can also cast a Patronus. It just doesn’t discuss this possibility, because it’s so vanishingly rare. So far there aren’t any examples of Animagi who have a different animal form to their Patronus, but the sample is so small that we can’t draw any meaningful conclusions either way.